# Decimal control in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to round the decimal places to two 
and I use

```
proc tabulate data=temporary;
class ageclass;
var age;
table ageclass, age*(mean*f=numx12.2 ); run;
```

and I get the solution as 
59.00 and 62.15

What I want to do is if it is not .00 then I want it to have 2 decimals and if it is .00 then I want to round off the value. 
like 59 and 62.15. 
is there any way to do it

Comment: `BESTD6.2` might work if your data are always 10<=age<=99ages, but it's not really exactly what you want (and doesn't use the comma for the decimal place).  You might need to either post process the data or use a picture format - I don't recall off the top of my head a way to do this properly for proc tabulate.

Comment: Another alternative would be to run the following: data temporary; set temporary; age=round(age, 0.01); run; This would give you the rounding of 2 decimal points only when the 2 decimals are different than .00. However, the decimals are separated by a dot (.) and not a comma (,) which I don't know if it makes any difference for you.

Comment: Joe It doesnt matter what procedure we use., but the output is as I just explained. 
@Noob_Strider , we here use commas, European style. Anyways. 
I want that in the output.. like when calculating mean or percentage.. Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunate that MAXDEC option from PROC MEANS isn't on PROC TABULATE.

Answer (score 0):

`BESTD6.2` format will probably work for your purpose, if your ages are >= 10 and <= 99, as it will display a 2 digit number as II.DD .  It will not work if you have age means > 100 or < 10 as it might make different choices.

BESTD attempts to align decimals, and will use an integer format for integers; but it does make some odd choices when it's not an integer, so it's best used only if it happens to work for your purpose.

Otherwise, you should probably output the data to a dataset and round it, then `proc print` it back out (or report or tabulate or whatever works for you) using `BEST.`